# How can my users answer to one email and that goes to user account on website?

Tags: php, email

Ok, so here's a difficult question for me.

I have searched on Google for some solutions but I couldn't yet make it clear on my mind.

Do you know some way of sending a message through the website "internal messaging system" (it's working ok) and then (this is the difficult part), just as it happens with eBay or Freelancer or many others, if user answers to that message on his email box, that can go to other user website account?

How can I be able to do that?

Website is in PHP and I am using phpmailer and my server SMTP credentials to send emails.

I imagine it's probably needed some POP configurations in order to receive the emails and some way to create an individual and unique email address so when people answers, it can go directly to that user.

Btw, website is www.mf.pt.la

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want the email to end up in mailbox, but in database of your web application. This usually involves forwarding all email to some mailbox or matching a patern to an executable script. You have to consult your smtp server documentation, but it might be as simle as creating .forward file in mailboxes account home directory with this content:

```
|/path/to/executable/script
```

`script` will receive the email, including all headers on stdin.

Now you need a way to identify, who should receive the message.

If you can forward email based on patern, you can place some identifier into the email address, this is what facebook does.

Or you can look for `In-Reply-To` email header, there you will find `Message-ID` of the email you send to the user. But sure, you either have to set it or get the autogenerated from phpmailer. Again, consult the manual.

Then there will be the most difficult part, extract the message itself from the email body :)

If it's not possible to forward incoming emails in your case, you might still have luck with cron job executing script that will fetch new emails from POP3 (or IMAP) account.